# In psycopg2 why would you ever use execute_batch over execute_values?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

In psycopg2 why would you ever use [execute_batch](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_batch) over [execute_values](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values)?

I know they're slightly different in what they algorithmically do but it seems
`execute_values` as far as I can tell does everything `execute_batch` can do but faster.

Answer (score 3):

I think that execute_values needs to package its parameters up specifically into a VALUES list.  This is fine for INSERT, but for UPDATE and DELETE it can be a bit awkward to rewrite them into joins against a VALUES list, rather than just a series of statements.